# Laravel: can't get post data using Postman form-data

Tags: php, laravel, postman, lumen

Currently I'm developing a RESTful API so I created a method to upload images but can't the post data using Postman form-data

Here's the screenshot of the request on the Postman.
[image]

I've tried to print the request but still can't get the data.

Upload image code

```php
public function fileUpload(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //print_r($request->file('photo'));
        //exit;
        $rules = [
            'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:2048'
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $rules);

        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            $file = $request->file('photo');
            $filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $request->file('photo')->move(public_path('storage/images'), $filename);
        }

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Image successfully uploaded'], 200);
    }
```

I want to get post data(photo) through laravel request.

Comment: What headers are you setting on the request? Does it pass validation? Are you sure it's hitting the controller method? What response do you get from the application?

Comment: What version of the app is that, looks like it's a few major versions behind.

Comment: @AndrewWillis the settings on the headers is Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Postman will automatically put that header when I'm clicking the "form-data" in the body.

Comment: @DannyDainton I've tried the new versions too still can't get the post data using laravel request.

Comment: @Kboyz what about my other questions? Is it definately hitting the controller?